# Get Key & value in json using Object.keys Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get the key and the value of the json but with my method I only get the value.

My question is how to get the key and the name together?

in my example I need to get carTwo and name and rockect2 and name.

thanks in advance.

**json**

```
{
 "cars": {
   "carOne": [],
   "carTwo": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Tesla X"
    },
   ]
  },
 "rockets": {
   "rocket1": [],
   "rocket2": [
    {
      "id": "123456",
      "name": "Falcon 9"
    },
   ]
  }
}
```

**ts.file**

```
get(){
 this.service.getAll().subscribe((data:IBrand) => {
  Object.keys(data).map(keys:string) => {
   let brands: Ibrand[] = data[key];
    for(let brand of brands) {
     let brandType = brand.name;
      this.array.push(brandType);
   }
  }
 })
}
```

**interface**

```
export interface IBrand {
 id:string;
 name:string;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Please add the expected ouptput for the current input.

Comment: I would like to have this if that is your question: carTwo => Tesla X".  in my html but for the moment I only have Tesla X  Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate the keys and get the value based off that key. Also, you have a nested structure which means just `Object.keys` would not suffice. You would have to dive into some properties and get the information you need.

Here is a sample,

```
const data = {
 "cars": {
   "carOne": [],
   "carTwo": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Tesla X"
    },
   ]
  },
 "rockets": {
   "rocket1": [],
   "rocket2": [
    {
      "id": "123456",
      "name": "Falcon 9"
    },
   ]
  }
};

const printNameAndIdPropertyData = (info: any) => {
    for(const key of Object.keys(info)) {
        if(Array.isArray(info[key])){
            const arrayData: Array<any> = info[key];
            if(arrayData && arrayData.length){
                console.log(key);
                for(const car of info[key]){
                    // NOTE: id and name here are not strongly typed. so, you must adjust if you want that. 
                    console.log(car.id);
                    console.log(car.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

printNameAndIdPropertyData(data.cars);
printNameAndIdPropertyData(data.rockets);
```

Note that this is a sample and may not full cover all your needs. So, you must change as per your requirement.